# Вызов метода подменой контекста

Tags: javascript

Если я хочу вызвать функцию из прототипа массивов, например forEach, для коллекции, допустим NodeList, то какой вариант лучше избрать?

1. `[].forEach.call(collection, function (element) {});`
2. `Array.prototype.forEach.call(collection, function(element) {});`

Есть предположение что в первом случае отработает конструктор массива. Второй случай этим не страдает. Так ли это?

Comment: разницы нет. Результат будет таким же, а внутренняя реализация зависит от среды исполнения.

Comment: В первом случае, кстати, забыт вызов `call`, как и во втором впрочем.

Comment: точно, спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно спецификации в первом случае будет происходить следующее:

1. создание массива
2. поиска в созданном массиве свойства `forEach`: fail
3. получение прототипа созданного массива
4. поиск свойства `forEach` в прототипе: OK
5. вызов функции

---

Во втором случае:

1. получение значения для `Array`
2. поиск в полученном значении свойства `prototype`
3. поиск свойства `forEach`
4. вызов функции

---

Однако стоит отметить, что в зависимости от конкретной реализации и различных оптимизаций оба примера могут быть сведены к одному и тому же.

Если провести замеры, то некоторые бразузеры могут показать незначительное различие, а некоторые, например хром, показывают, что различие в размере погрешности.

Поэтому на вопрос: какой способ лучше выбрать? можно дать ответ: из приведенных - любой.

Кроме того, для итерации по `NodeList` можно воспользоваться недавно добавленным методом `forEach` напрямую.